# Chebyshev's inequality application and convergence - practical example

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

> Let $W_n$ be a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{b^2}{n^{2p}}$, with $p>0$ and $b$ and $\mu$ constants.
>
> **Show that**
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} P(|W_n-\mu| \leq \epsilon) = 1 $$

The solution applies Chebychevs:
$$ P(|W_n-\mu| \leq \epsilon) = 1 - P(|W_n-\mu| > \epsilon) $$
$$ \geq 1 - P(|W_n-\mu| \geq \epsilon) $$
$$ = 1 - P(|W_n-\mu| \geq \frac{\epsilon n^p}{b} \frac{b}{n^p}) $$
$$ \geq 1 - \frac{1}{(\frac{\epsilon n^p}{b})^2}$$

and then taking the limit $n\to\infty$.

I do not understand the change of signs in the second line?

Also where does $\frac{\epsilon n^p}{b} \frac{b}{n^p} $  in the third line come from?

**Does this imply $W_n$ converges in probability to $p$ ?**

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} P(|W_n-\mu| \geq \epsilon) = 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty}P(|W_n-\mu| < \epsilon) \leq 1 - \lim_{n\to\infty} P(|W_n-\mu| \leq \epsilon) = 0$$

So, this i do not understand. An explanation in plain english of this. This is the first time i worked on exercises for convergence.

Comment: $W_n$ converges in probability to $\mu$ rather.

Comment: In the third line $P(|X-\mu|\geq k\cdot  \sigma)\leq \frac1{k^2}$ is used.

Comment: @callculus - an alternative would be to use $P(|X-\mu|\geq t)\leq \dfrac{\sigma^2}{t^2}$ for $t \gt 0$

Comment: @Henry Sure. I have used the other one in order that the OP can insert directly the terms for $k$ and $\sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $P(|W_n-\mu| \leq \epsilon) = 1 - P(|W_n-\mu| > \epsilon)$ is saying that the probability $W_n$ being strictly within $\epsilon$ of $\mu$ is the same as the probability that the difference is *not* $\epsilon$ or more.
- $1 - P(|W_n-\mu| > \epsilon) \ge 1 - P(|W_n-\mu| \geq \epsilon)$ is that the probability of the difference between $W_n$ and $\mu$ *not* being $\epsilon$ or more is greater than or equal to the probability that the difference is not strictly more than $\epsilon$.
- Using $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon n^p}{b} \frac{b}{n^p}$ gets the variance of $\frac{b}{n^p}$ into the expression and so allows Chebyshev's inequality to be applied
- You can apply limits to the probability inequalities providing that the limits exist.  Since there is a lower bound on the probabilities of $1 - \frac{1}{(\frac{\epsilon n^p}{b})^2}$ which approaches $1$ as $n$ increases, these limits do exist and are $1$

Comment: very understandable answer, thanks! There is just one thing. The variance is $\frac{b^2}{n^{2p}}$, so in the third point, shouldn't it be $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon n^{2p}}{b}\frac{b}{n^{2p}}$ ?

Comment: also according to my script, Chebychev's inequality is $$P(|X-\mu|>\epsilon)\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$$ so i don't understand why it is necesary to go from $1-P(|W_n-\mu|>\epsilon)$ to  $1-P(|W_n-\mu| \geq \epsilon)$ ?

Comment: @user1607 - see the comments from callculus and me to your original question: the two formulations are equivalent